# How to handle conditional JSON response from API with pagination

Tags: go, pagination, slice

I have a scenario where I send a request to a 3rd party API that provides a response like the following:

```
data: [
    {
        id: 111,
        highPriorityItems: [
            {
                "time": "2022-01-01T00:00:50Z",
                "price": 5000.55
            },
            {
                "time": "2022-01-02T13:00:50Z",
                "price": 5600.55
            },
            ...
        ],
        lowPriorityItems: [
            {
                "time": "2022-03-01T00:12:50Z",
                "price": 9000.55
            },
            {
                "time": "2022-03-02T22:00:50Z",
                "price": 6700.55
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

`lowPriorityItems` is always there, whereas `highPriorityItems` is not always there. My desired result is to use `highPriorityItems` if it is there and capture that data.

The tricky part is that the API is paginated and can return a lot of separate objects with these embedded priorityItem arrays, meaning that one response might only show the `lowPriorityItems` for a particular `id` and the next paginated response might show the `highPriorityItems` array for the same `id`.

I'd like to end up at a final result where I just have the ID and both `lowPriorityItems` and `highPriorityItems` slices in a single `struct`. if `highPriorityItems` is empty I can then choose to use the `lowPriorityItems` after I have both slices side by side in a result.

Trying to think of a succinct and efficient way to handle this idea. Current thoughts:

````
package main


type Payload struct {
    Data []Entity `json:"data"`
}

type Entity struct {
    Id string `json:"id"`
    HighPriorityItems []Item `json:"highPriorityItems"`
    LowPriorityItems []Item `json:"lowPriorityItems"`
}

type Item struct {
    time string
    price float64
}

func main() {

    payloads := []&Payload{}
    
    for _, req := requests {
        // Boilerplate to unmarshal response into Payload struct and append to our slice of Payloads
        // Each response gets appended to our slice of payloads
        payloads = append(payloads, payload)
    
    }    

    // Here is where I am thinking that I need logic to essentially check if I have already 
    // Received a payload that has an object with the Id of the paginated payload, and if it does, append to our ```Entity``` priorityItem slices for that specific idea (so I can maintain a complete collection of both item types for the same ```id```
    // Does it make sense to each time loop over my current payload list and check for Ids (seems expensive) or maybe utilize another data structure (map w/ structs?) in some way?
  
}
````

Answer (score 1):

Record the items in a map of entities keyed by id:

```
entities := make(map[string]*Entity)
```

For each response, iterate over the entities.  Add entity to map if first one, else append items to first entity.

```
for i := range resp.Data {    
    e := &resp.Data[i] // pointer to slice element 
    if me, ok := entities[e.Id]; !ok {
        entities[e.Id] = me
    } else {
        me.LowPriorityItems = append(me.LowPriorityItems, e.LowPriorityItems...)
        me.HighPriorityItems = append(me.HighPriorityItems, e.HighPriorityItems...)
    }
}
```

Loop over the map values to access the entities:

```
for _, e := range entities {
    // do something with e
}
```

Comment: What is ```e := &p.Data[i]``` referencing? What is the ```p```?